# Trim a string based on specific character in Laravel Query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to trim string based on specific character (e.g "-", ":", ";") inside Laravel Query.

```
$users = User::select("USERID as id", DB::raw("CONCAT(CONCAT(NAME, ' - '), CONCAT(CONCAT(NUMBER, ' - '), ROLE)) as text"))
            ->whereNotNull('name')
            ->orderBy('name');
```

I want the number to be cut when there is special character

NUMBER example: 123456:9

NUMBER expected: 123456

User selected result would be : John Doe - 123456 - Admin

Answer (score 0):

I believe that trim is not what you are looking for. As trim is usually used to extract every character(s) from a string and leave the rest of it.

If your database server is SQL you could use a combination of functions, for instance:

```
SELECT LEFT('123456:9', CHARINDEX(':', '123456:9') - 1);
```

This will return all the characters on the left of the first match of the special character.

Comment: Hi, i'm using postgresql for my database.
And also, i know trim is not what i'm looking for but i couldn't find any word to describe it :D
I'm looking for a function like strtok() in php but it doesn't work in db query.

Comment: Well in php you have the strtok() function, that is similar to the explode(). However I don't think you can apply a php function inside the DB:raw()